# Change the title size in scrartcl

Tags: fontsize, titles, koma-script

I'd like to use a smaller title. I'm using the `scrartcl` documentclass from the [KOMA-Script bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). I can change it's color font but not it's size.

```
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries\small}
```

Everything works exept the size.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  The `scr` collection of classes are based on some careful design decisions, and in particular, the documentation notes that the `\setkomafont` command will not change the size of titles (which are `\huge` be default).  However, you can write `\title{\large My title}` instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation (`scrguien`) says about the title (I highlighted the relevant part):

> The title is output with a very large font size. Besides the change of
>   size, the settings for the element title also take effect. By default
>   these settings are identical to the settings for the element
>   disposition (see table 3.2, page 51). The default settings may be
>   changed using the commands `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont` (see
>   section 3.6, page 51). **The font size is, however, not affected** (see
>   table 3.2, page 59).

The reason why the change of font size performed with `\setkomafont` won't have effect is because `scrartcl.cls` uses

```
\titlefont\huge \@title\par
```

so any modification to the font size made with  `\setkomafont` (applied through `\titlefont`) will be overwritten by the `\ḩuge` command after `\titlefont`.

Here's a possible solution using the `etoolbox` package to patch the internal command `\@maketitle` to change the default `\huge` (instead of `\small` use the desired size):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\titlefont\huge}{\titlefont\small}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **lockstep** mentions, the above solution will produce the desired solution if the  `titlepage` option is false (which is the default). If the `titlepage` option is set to true, one can patch `\maketitle` with the help of the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlefont\huge}{\titlefont\small}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Here's some code that will work whether `titlepage` is set to true or false:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlefont\huge}{\titlefont\small}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\titlefont\huge}{\titlefont\small}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Another option (mentioned by **Andrew Swann** in a comment), but I am not sure if this will have undesired side effects, is to 
use the font size switch directly in the argument of `\title`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\title{\small The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `xpatch` and not `regexpatch` for this kind of patches (the latter is still unstable).

Comment: @egreg good to know. I've made the change. Thank you.

Comment: Could you check your answers still work? I'm running Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013) on OS X Mavericks, and the MWE produces title text of the same size as usual. Substituting ```\Large``` or even ```\tiny``` makes no difference to the output. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina This solution does not work any more, at least the ones with etoolbox or xpatch.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks for the heads up! I'll take a look at this and propose an updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete answer, but turning on `\tracingpatches` helped me see that the patch command wasn't working because it isn't matching on the second argument in the `\patchcmd` command. So I simplified the change:

```
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\huge}{\Large}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This simplification works where there is no titlepage option is true, but from looking at the scrartcl.cls file, I suspect this will change size for `\part` commands as well.

Perhaps someone who knows what they're doing could please produce a robust version? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've now found another approach that works, namely **renewing** the `\maketitle` command. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
   \begin{center}
     {\large\bfseries\@title\par\vspace{0.3em}}
     {\scshape\@author, \@date}
   \end{center}
}
\makeatother
```

This reduces the size of the title, author and date, puts the latter two on the same line, and puts them in small caps.

You'll need someone more expert than I am to comment where patching or renewing is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution by H. Voß in one of its books:

```
\addtokomafont{title}{\let\huge\Large}
```